# rails has_many in show just displays table name

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following has_many association.

```
class Indicator < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :statement, required: false
  belongs_to :identity, required: false
  belongs_to :phase, required: false
end

class Statement < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :student, required: false
  has_many :indicators   
  has_many :identities, through: :indicators 
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :identities
end

class Identity < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :indicators   
  has_many :statements, through: :indicators 
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :statements
  has_many :phases
end

class Phase < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :indicators
  belongs_to :identity, required: false
end
```

I'm looking to call the results in the statement show.html.erb. The `<%= l.phases.name %>` portion of the below code displays 'Phase', which is the table name and not the value of name.

```
<table>
 <th>Description</th>
 <th>Phase</th>
 <% @statement.identities.each do |l| %>
   <tr>
    <td><%= l.description %></td>
    <td><%= l.phases.name %></td>
   </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

This is how the indicator table is setup:

```
| id | statement_id | identity_id | phase_id |
| 1  |      2       |      1      |    3     |
| 2  |      2       |      2      |    2     |
| 3  |      3       |      1      |    1     |
| 4  |      3       |      2      |    1     |
```

Answer (score 1):

Since it has many phases you should display the name of each phase with a loop.

```
<% l.phases.each do |p| %>
<%= p.name %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks @shannon. I have tried that, but seems to list all associated identity_ids. I think I may have my associations wrong. I have updated the question above to show how my indicator table is structured.

Answer (score 0):

Your associations are incorrect. Since Identity `has_many :phases` and Phase `belongs_to :identity`, there is no reason to specify a through option. You would then do

```
<% @statement.identities.each do |l| %>
   <tr>
    <td><%= l.description %></td>
    <td><%= l.phases.pluck(:name) %></td>
   </tr>
  <% end %>
```

to retrieve the name of each of the phases for a particular instance of Identity.

Comment: Thanks MisterCal. The above stills gives me an array/hash. #<Phase::ActiveRecord_AssociationRelation:0x007fb56c752460>

Comment: try pluck(:name) instead of select, which should return the value and not the actual object. edited above

Comment: No luck. It's looking for the key id in phases. **no such column: phases.identity_id: SELECT "phases"."name" FROM "phases" WHERE "phases"."identity_id" = ?**. I'm looking to match in the indicator table listed above. Think I have confessed myself rightly.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do with the indicator model?  If i'm not mistaken, you have to set up a foreign key in your phases table. Use add_foreign_key :phases, :identities in a migration. This will allow you to show all phases which belong to identities

Comment: When you want to show all the phases that belong to identity, it can only be done through identity: references,  in other words, having an identity_id  foreign key reference on your Phase model

Comment: So the indicator model is storing each foreign key for the 3 tables (statement, identity, phase). When creating a statement, you can add identities, in which have a phase. As i understand adding an foreign key to the phase model will achieve nothing, as the foreign key is being stored in the indicator table.

Comment: the indicator model foreign key will only get you so far as being able to show all indicators through phases.  While it serves well as a join table for your statement and identity models, you will need to add a foreign key to your phases table with a migration. Even if your indicator contains all 3 foreign keys,  you will still need an `identity_id` foreign key on your phases model so that your phases know who they belong to.

Comment: run a migration with   `add_foreign_key :phases, :identities`   and your associations will work the way you want them to

Comment: Right. So there is no way to achieve this without adding the foreign key. I ask as the phase table is pre-populated with results, and one is selected from a dropdown upon creation.

Comment: I understand what you're trying to achieve in the table, but the only other way to do it would be to reference the phases according to their indicator. Something like `@indicator.phase` for each indicator instance. Since you already have a `belongs_to :identity` declaration in your Phase model, however  it would be much simpler, and better convention, to add the corresponding foreign key to the phases table.

Comment: Thanks MisterCal. I shall look further into these methods.

Comment: No problem. A great place to start would be the rails guides, particularly associations http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html its pretty thorough and covers all the methods you can do according to which associations you have.